# Android use Intent to send a list of Parcelable objects which contain a list of another Parcelable objects

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android app, I want to use `Intent` to pass a list of `SingleGroup` to another `Activity` where each `SingleGroup` object contains a list of `SingleImage`, here are class for `SingleImage` and `SingleGroup`:

```
public class SingleImage implements Parcelable{

public  String name;
public  int drawableId;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getDrawableId() {
    return drawableId;
}

public void setDrawableId(int drawableId) {
    this.drawableId = drawableId;
}

public SingleImage(String name, int drawableId)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.drawableId = drawableId;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<SingleImage> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<SingleImage>()
{
    public SingleImage createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new SingleImage(in);
    }

    public SingleImage[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new SingleImage[size];
    }
};

private SingleImage(Parcel in)
{
    name = in.readString();
    drawableId = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeInt(drawableId);
}
}
```

Here is SingleGroup class:

```
public class SingleGroup implements Parcelable{
private static final String TAG = "SINGLEGROUP";
private ArrayList<SingleImage> images =  new ArrayList<SingleImage>(0);
private String myTitle;
private String groupDesc;

public SingleGroup(String mTitle, String desc, ArrayList<SingleImage> imagesList) {
    this.myTitle = mTitle;
    this.groupDesc = desc;
    this.images = imagesList;
}

public String getGroupDesc() {
    return groupDesc;
}

public String getMyTitle() {
    return myTitle;
}

public void setMyTitle(String myTitle) {
    this.myTitle = myTitle;
}

public ArrayList<SingleImage> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(ArrayList<SingleImage> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<SingleGroup> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<SingleGroup>()
{
    public SingleGroup createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new SingleGroup(in);
    }

    public SingleGroup[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new SingleGroup[size];
    }
};

private SingleGroup(Parcel in)
{
    myTitle = in.readString();
    groupDesc = in.readString();

     //problem maybe here
    in.readTypedList(images,SingleImage.CREATOR);
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(myTitle);
    dest.writeString(groupDesc);

    //problem maybe here
    dest.writeTypedList(images);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String result = "myTitle "+myTitle+" desc "+ groupDesc + " imagesize "+images.size();
    return result;
}
}
```

It works ok when calling to pass `ArrayList<SingleImage>` through `Intent`,
while when I called to pass `ArrayLlist<SingleGroup>` through `Intent` I got error:

> Parcel android.os.Parcel@3c4c6743: Unmarshalling unknown type code
>   3211379 at offset 224

Any idea? Thanks in advance

----------------  Update ----------------
I have changed `in.readTypedList(images, null);` to `in.readTypedList(images, SingleImage.CREATOR);` but it still not working. same unmarshalling error

----------------  Problem Solved  --------------
Thanks to Keita. The real problem is not actually listed in my code. When I passing the parcelable object, I should also include some other attributes which I missed.
Strongly recommend AS plugin [Android Parcelable code generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be pass SingleImage.CREATOR into method readTypedList instead of "null" value

```
private SingleGroup(Parcel in)
{
    myTitle = in.readString();
    groupDesc = in.readString();

     //problem maybe here
    in.readTypedList(images, SingleImage.CREATOR);
}
```

Comment: you can try with plugin [Android Parcelable code generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332), then use plugin to Generate parcelable code for your parcelable Object

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. That is what i always do and it work:

```
private SingleGroup(Parcel in)
{
    myTitle = in.readString();
    groupDesc = in.readString();

     //problem maybe here
    in.createTypedArrayList(SingleImage.CREATOR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is *serialize*. So try to this

`public class SingleImage implements Serializable{
....
}`

Refer this: [ArrayList Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)